# Passing today's date in soapui with specific format

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

I want to pass today's date in this format **2020-12-07T20:15:15.783-06:00** by using this groovy script in soapui

```
${= new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" )}
```

But I am getting the following error

> Script48.groovy: 1: unexpected char: '' @ line 1, column 20.
> new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" )```

Not sure what I am missing ? I want the date format to be matching the example.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
myTimestamp = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" )
log.info "${myTimestamp}"
```